creating file from groovy code inside Jenkinsfile
I'm trying to create a json file from groovy code that is called from Jenkinsfile. The groovy code seems to work (i.e at the end of the code I list the files in the directory and I see the file is listed there), but when I try try to access that file from a later stage from shell or python then the file isn't there.
stage {
    steps {
        script {
            if (foo.bar()) {
                echo "set_var: " + datastore.set_var(WORKSPACE, "meow")
                sh(script: "pwd ; ls -l")
            }
        }
    }
}

datastore.groovy:
    @NonCPS
    def static set_var(workspaceDir, String text) {
        def filePath = "${workspaceDir}/datastore.json"
        def data = [:]
        def file = new File(filePath)
        if (file.exists()) {
            data = JSON_SLURPER.parse(file)
        } else {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs()
            file.createNewFile()
        }
        data["text"] = text
        def json = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
        def files = ""
        try {
            file.write(json)
            file.getParentFile().eachFile { f -> files += f.getName() + "\n" }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error writing to file: ${file.getAbsolutePath()}: ${e}"
        }
        return "Wrote text: ${text} to file: ${file.getAbsolutePath()}; files: ${files}"
    }

When I run the job in jenkins I see this:
set_var: Wrote key: FAIL_REASON, text: meow to file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/jobname/91/datastore.json; files: datastore.json

13:39:34  [Pipeline] sh
13:39:34  + pwd
13:39:34  /home/ubuntu/workspace/jobname/91
13:39:34  + ls -l
13:39:34  total 24
13:39:34  -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   78 Jul  9 10:39 Dockerfile
13:39:34  -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  230 Jul  9 10:39 README.md
13:39:34  drwxrwxr-x 6 1000 1000 4096 Jul  9 10:39 jenkins
13:39:34  -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 1209 Jul  9 10:39 pipeline.py
13:39:34  -rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000   27 Jul  9 10:39 requirements.txt
13:39:34  drwxrwxr-x 4 1000 1000 4096 Jul  9 10:39 src

So it looks like the /home/ubuntu/workspace/jobname/91 directory that the groovy sees is different from the /home/ubuntu/workspace/jobname/91 that shell/python see.

Where your datastore.groovy is located? is it configured as a shared library? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

@daggett, yes, it's in the vars/ directory, that's why I am able to call it as datastore.set_var() from the Jenkinsfile

There is a Pipeline Utility Steps plugin that provides a writeJSON step. There is a reason for that - File works with the filesystem on the built-in agent (that's where all the groovy code is executed), but I would go on a limb here and say that your pipeline is running on an agent. With its own filesystem.

Indeed it runs on an agent. So why don't they (groovy, sh) both see the same files? They're called from the same step.

Groovy (actually Groovy based DSL that Jenkins uses) always runs on the built-in agent because it can access a lot of Jenkins internals (like build history, plugin configurations, job definitions) and making all that available from outside of Jenkins would mean going the API-first route, and that's just not how Jenkins was written, I think.

Ok, so I'll call the same function from a python file. That works from other parts of the code, I. hope it'll also work from here... I don't like that part of the (legacy) code of the Jenkinsfile is calling python scripts as sh(), I wanted to do this from groovy, so it can be called directly...
